# How to conditionally select a column in an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to do something like:

```
select (if lookup = 8 then 08 else lookup) lookup
  , //more columns
from lookup_table
order by lookup
```

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't seem to like this syntax, and I am failing to discover why or find what other function I should be using.

Basically, if the lookup value is 8, I want to get 08, otherwise I want the value of lookup. I'm sure I'm just being stupid.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want a case statement:

```
select (case when lookup = 8 then 8 else lookup end) as lookup
```

If `lookup` is a character string, you probably want:

```
select (case when lookup = '08' then '08' else lookup end) as lookup
```

If `lookup` is an integer and you want to convert it to a string, then:

```
select (case when lookup = 8 then to_char(lookup, '00') else to_char(lookup, '00') end) as lookup
```

However, that would seem redundant to me.