# How to select columns conditionally in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select a data from **Oracle** . However I have a column - `CHILD_IDN` -  that decides which column is right for me . If the  column is having an idn then I need to pick `CHILD` from the table else by default I should pick the `PARENT` . MSSQL allows a simple CASE statement to work . 
But what about Oracle ? Is there a Oracle vs MSSQL compatible query for this ? I think its a non - normalized data hence need advice .

For example

```
TableA

1    PARENT  CHILD_IDN CHILD
2    Okay 
3    Cool    1         PickMe1 
4    Fine
5    Test
6    Bar     2         Pickme2
7    Hello   


Now the result expected is 

Okay 
PickMe1
Fine
Test
Pickme2
Hellow
```

Comment: could you just use coalesce and ignore childidn?  ` select coalease(child, parent) as Result`  coalesce takes the first non-null value in a series.  it appears you want to pull in all child if they exist and if not the parent.  Coalese does this fairly well.

Comment: Right would have a look at coalease , but i need to check the fist non-null value ? Need to check that .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement in Oracle too. like,

```
SELECT CASE WHEN child_idn IS NOT NULL THEN child 
       ELSE parent 
       END
FROM   tableA;
```

Comment: I get Error starting at line 2 in command:
SELECT CASE WHEN end_dt IS NOT NULL THEN end_dt ELSE start_dt
FROM   Test
Error at Command Line:2 Column:61
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: @Nishant, Please find the modified answer. `SELECT CASE WHEN end_dt IS NOT NULL THEN end_dt ELSE start_dt END FROM Test;`

Comment: @Nishant, you missed 'END' keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `case`:

```
select (case when child_idn = 2 then child else parent
        end)
from table t;
```

This is standard SQL and should work in either database.

Note:  this assumes that the "blank" values are `NULL` and uses the fact that the condition will fail on a `NULL` value.  You can also be explicit if you want:

```
select (case when child_idn = 1 then parent
             when child_idn = 2 then child
             else parent
        end)
```

Comment: Thanks I just notice : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665220/how-to-conditionally-select-a-column-in-an-oracle-query in similar essence .

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` or `DECODE` statement as below:

**Test Data**

```
WITH TABLEA AS
(
SELECT 1 SLNO, 'OKAY' PARENT, '' CHILD_ID, '' CHILD FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 2 SLNO, 'COOL' PARENT, '1' CHILD_ID, 'PICKME1' CHILD FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 3 SLNO, 'FINE' PARENT, '' CHILD_ID, '' CHILD FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 4 SLNO, 'TEST' PARENT, '' CHILD_ID, '' CHILD FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 6 SLNO, 'BAR' PARENT, '2' CHILD_ID, 'PICKME2' CHILD FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 7 SLNO, 'HELLO' PARENT, '' CHILD_ID, '' CHILD FROM DUAL
)
```

**Alternative 1:** with Decode

```
SELECT DECODE(CHILD_ID,'',PARENT,CHILD) CHILD
FROM TABLEA
```

**Alternative 2**: With Case

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CHILD_ID IS NOT NULL THEN child 
       ELSE parent 
       END) value
FROM TABLEA
```

The above query with test data provides the expected result as asked in the question!

Comment: Yes but that is too much of a hardcoding :) But yes another way to think of .

Comment: @Nishant: The query is hardly 2 or 3 lines only. I have included the test data also with the with clause, so that you can just run the query and check for the output.

Comment: Do you want me to put the queries separately without test data?

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice that - I am new to DB . Thats interesting , I have edited the answer . I will check the decode option - It it Oracle MSSQL compatible ?

Comment: It is 100% oracle compatible.